# Need help to get the Html output in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

With below script, I am able to get the output in deploy as a web app "You are accessing this file from 124.153.80.230"

I am trying to import or copy this output in google sheet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">

  </head>
  <body>

<p id="ip"></p>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var userip;
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://l2.io/ip.js?var=userip"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.write("You are accessing this file from :", userip);
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
function doGet() {
 var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('getip');
  t.data = SpreadsheetApp
      .openById('11s8K2-8jhz9RzKRLezl9pqwf5fMolqxw36lNNjJdYdA')
      .getActiveSheet()
      .getDataRange()
      .getValues();
  return t.evaluate();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this sample script? It retrieves the value using `google.script.run`. The retrieved value is imported to Spreadsheet.

#### HTML :

Filename is `getip.html`.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://l2.io/ip.js?var=userip"></script>
    <script>
      $(function () {
        $("#ip").html(userip);
        google.script.run.getvalue(userip);
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="ip"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### GAS :

```
function doGet() {
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('getip').evaluate();
}

function getvalue(value){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("### Spreadsheet ID ###").getActiveSheet();
  ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow()+1,1).setValue(value);
}
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks...But it's copied the data in sheet as "undefined"

Comment: @Kiiran Shetty Relieved to hear it. Thank you.

Comment: I need a small help here - I want to create a trigger(When from Open) script should run 
do i need to modify the script function doGet(e)

Comment: I cannot understand what you want to do. I'm sorry. Can you submit your another question with the detailed information as a new question?